# How can I sort in an SQL statement, while giving numbers a lower value than characters?

Tags: oracle, sorting, plsql

How can I sort in an SQL statement, while giving numbers a lower value than characters?

e.g.:

- 'iPad Wi-Fi' should appear before 'iPad 2 Wi-Fi'
- 'iPad 2 Wi-Fi' should appear before 'iPad 3 Wi-Fi'
- 'iPad 3 Wi-Fi' should appear before 'iPhone'
- 'iPhone' should appear before 'iPhone 2'

Comment: @EvilTeach Before asking, I was only able to check if a value is numeric. I was trying to figure out how to iterate through the characters and apply the numeric test (a wrong approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to have a separate column which you populate in a way that it sorts as you want it.

Then make sure that it remains consistent by ensuring it's set by an insert/update trigger.

By using a separate column set on insert/update, you guarantee the cost of calculating this order is done only where needed, not every time you `select`. It's often the case that DBAs will sacrifice space to get more time.

And the use of triggers maintains the ACID properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from your_table
order by 
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(name, '9', '0'), '8', '1'), '7', '2'), '6', '3'), '5', '4') asc
```

Comment: @[juergen d] +1 Thanks! I fixed the statement by putting an 'a' before the number. Also, there was no need to reverse the numerical order. Also made it case-insensitive. This works:  select *
from yourtable
order by lower(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(yourcolumn, '9', 'Z9'), '8', 'Z8'), '7', 'Z7'), '6', 'Z7'), '5', 'Z5'), '4', 'Z4'), '3', 'Z3'), '2', 'Z2'), '1', 'Z1'), '0', 'Z0'))